# Wordpress : how to use a picture instead a title of a category

Tags: wordpress, categories

I need to use picture instead of category's title. How can I do ?

Comment: I'm making a website for a hostel. I have 4 categories : "1 star", "2 stars", "3 stars", "4 stars". Instead of these titles, i would like to use pictures (a picture with 1 star, another with 2 stars...). Perhaps whith CSS ???

Comment: First of all you need to start solving problem by yourself and only after that ask questions

Comment: Tibbers, I tried with fontawesome too but it's not working. I really don't know how to to ?

Comment: Make a jsfiddle and pust some code there so we can evaluate, and see why it's not working.

Comment: OK, but i don't know loops and source code of wordpress and how to attached an image for each category. I'm a specialiste of a french CMS SPIP http://www.spip.net/en_rubrique57.html. But wordpress is new for me.

Comment: There is a half of the million ways to put pictures instead of titles even without going deeply in the code. But without your evidence of putting some effort we can't help.